# Run node script with a global variable

Tags: environment-variables, nodejs, paths

I have a node script index.js with a node_modules folder.

```
/script/myTestJscript/index.js
/script/myTestJscript/node_modules
/script/myTestJscript/package.json
```

I could run the script with the command `./index.js`

How can I make the script run whith a global command, for example running the script by calling the command mytestscript in the console?

I tried to use `sudo ln -s ./script/myTestJscript/index.js mytestscript` but this is not working

Answer (score 1):

You should put the symlink in a directory which is included in `PATH`. As an example you could do:

```
sudo ln -s /script/myTestJscript/index.js /usr/local/bin/mytestscript
```